# Does C# support a __call__ method?

Tags: c#

Python has this magic [`__call__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method that gets called when the object is called like a function. Does C# support something similar?

---

Specifically, I was hoping for a way to use delegates and objects interchangeably. Trying to design an API where a user can pass in a list of functions, but sometimes those functions need some initial params, in which case they'd use one of those callable objects instead.

Answer (score 11):

Sure, if you inherit from [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx). I think you're after [TryInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryinvoke.aspx) which executes on `obj(...)`, but there are several other method you can override to handle casting, index access (`obj[idx]`), method invocations, property invocations, etc.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication {
    public static class ConsoleApp {
        public static void Main() {
            dynamic x = new MyDynamicObject();
            var result = x("awe", "some");

            Debug.Assert(result == "awesome");
        }
    }

    public class MyDynamicObject : DynamicObject {
        public override Boolean TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, Object[] args, out Object result) {
            result = args.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (builder, item) => builder.Append(item), builder => builder.ToString());
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Wow! - behold the awesome power of dynamic. I will probably never use this, but it is good to know....

Comment: **+1!** What the Hell?! Epic.

Answer (score 6):

I bow to Simon Svensson - who shows a way to do it if you inherit from DynamicObject - for a more strait forward non dynamic point of view:

Sorry but no - but there are types of objects that can be called - delegates for instance.

```
 Func<int, int> myDelagate = x=>x*2; 
 int four = myDelagate(2)
```

There is a default property though - that has to have at least one parameter and its access looks like an array access:

```
class Test1
{
    public int this[int i, int j]
    {
        get { return i * j; }
    }
}
```

Calling

```
        Test1 test1 = new Test1();
        int six = test1[2, 3];
```

Then you can do some really silly stuff with delegates like this:

```
class Test2 // I am not saying that this is a good idea. 
{
    private int MyFunc(int z, int i)
    {
    return z * i;
    }
    public Func<int, int> this[int i] { get { return x => MyFunc(x, i); } }
}
```

Then calling it looks weird like this:

```
        Test2 test = new Test2();
        test[2](2); // this is quite silly - don't use this.....
```

Answer (score 4):

This would be akin to overloading the function call operator (as is possible in C++). Unfortunately, this is not something which is supported in C#. The only objects that can be called like methods are instances of delegates.

Comment: I would second that - except to say fortunately you can't do this in C# - I hope I am not coming across too snobby. :)