# Make extended class callable in c#

Tags: c#, class

I am working on implementing the [project-chrono](https://github.com/projectchrono/chrono) physics engine into Unity3d. While most of it is working, the hangup is in a base class called ChLinkRotSpringCB, which is a rotating spring joint that takes a functor (just a callable class) that specifies what the spring forces are for a given offset angle. In python, you might set up one of these spring joints like this:

```
# Functor class implementing the torque for a ChLinkRotSpringCB link.
class MySpringTorque(chrono.TorqueFunctor):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MySpringTorque, self).__init__()

    def __call__(self,    #
                 time,    # current time
                 angle,   # relative angle of rotation
                 vel,     # relative angular speed
                 link):   # back-pointer to associated link

        torque = -spring_coef * (angle - rest_angle) - damping_coef * vel
        return torque

torque = MySpringTorque()
spring = chrono.ChLinkRotSpringCB()
spring.Initialize(body, ground, chrono.ChCoordsysD(rev_pos, rev_rot))
spring.RegisterTorqueFunctor(torque)
```

Notice the use of `__call__` to make the class (which extends `TorqueFunctor`) callable as a function.

Now here is my problem: In c# `RegisterTorqueFunctor` requires the instance you give it to be of type `TorqueFunctor`

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858733/does-c-sharp-support-a-call-method) that if I extend `DynamicObject` I can override the TryInvoke function which will make the class callable, but this obviously means though that I can't register it as a torque function as it isn't of type `TorqueFunctor`. C# doesn't allow inheriting from two base classes, so I can't just extend both.

**So, here be my question:** How do I extend the `TorqueFunctor` class while still making the instance callable as a function?

Comment: An inherited class in c# automatically becomes a type of the base class.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need your class to be directly invocable in addition to inheriting `TorqueFunctor`? You said `RegisterTorqueFunctor` takes a `TorqueFunctor`, but you also said "the hangup is in a base class called ChLinkRotSpringCB, which is a rotating spring joint that takes a functor (just a callable class)". Is that referring to `RegisterTorqueFunctor` or something else?

Comment: WHy don't you just define an interface `Callable<T>` that has function `T Call()` that executes what you want.

Comment: @Felk Yes, in order to create a ChLinkRotSpringCB joint, you need to configure it with ChLinkRotSpringCB.RegisterTorqueFunctor( <TorqueFunctor> )

Comment: Can you then please clarify what imposes the requirement of the class being directly invocable instead of just inheriting `TorqueFunctor`?

Comment: It is imposed by the project-chrono library which will invoke the class when calculating torque for the joint. Unfortunately, I can't change that requirement without editing project-chrono's source code.
http://api.projectchrono.org/classchrono_1_1_ch_link_rot_spring_c_b_1_1_torque_functor.html

Comment: @jdweng Yeah, but I need the inherited class to be directly invokable. Which AFAIK can only be done by inheriting the DynamicObject class.

Comment: When you create an instance of the object you have to use the inherited class not the base class.  If You have a Base class A and two children AA and AB the child classes can be cast to the parent (A)AA or (A)AB but not the reverse.