# How to define accumulator that can be infinitely chained as f(2)(3)(10)(100)?

Tags: c#

If possible I want to define a function, for example as an accumulator, that can be infinitely chained as follows:

- `f(2)` returns 2
- `f(2)(3)` returns 5
- `f(2)(3)(10)` returns 15
- `f(2)(3)(10)(100)` returns 115
- `f(2)(3)(10)(100)()()...` returns ...

```cs
static void Main()
{
    Func<int, Func<int, int>> f = (x) =>
    {
        return (y) =>
        {
            return x += y;
        };
    };

    Console.WriteLine(f(2)(3));
    // Console.WriteLine(f(2)(3)(10)); should return 15

}
```

Any idea?

Note: I am not asking `f(param int[] x){}` approach.

Comment: If `f(2)` returns 2, then how can `f(2)(3)` be valid?  You cannot *invoke* 2. 2 is not a function.

Comment: you could write an extension method for `int` to add for chaining

Comment: You can define a custom delegate, that returns an instance of itself. Then you could call `f(1)(2)`. But you can't change the return type, so how would you indicate that the result should be converted to a number or string rather than a delegate? In other words. Don't try to do this.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman: Maybe by overriding `ToString()` as `WriteLine(f(2))` equals to `WriteLine(f(2).ToString())`.

Comment: One thing you'll need to do if you figure out the other part is eventually called the returned function: `f(2)(3)(10)(100)();`

Comment: You can't override `ToString()` of a *delegate*. You could `f(2).Target.ToString()` but then I still wouldn't recommend it. Just implement some other function or operator, don't try to abuse function call syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f` cannot return an `int`, because you cannot invoke an `int` after calling `f` once. It can return a wrapper type that wraps an `int` though. `f` just needs to return the wrapper type, and then you can infinitely chain.

If you are fine with the indexer access syntax `[...]` instead of the method invocation syntax `(...)`, then you can just create a struct like this:

```
struct F {
    public int Count { get; }
    
    private F(int count) {
        Count = count;
    }
    public F this[int acc] => new F(Count + acc);

    // override ToString to return Count.ToString,
    // or an implicit conversion to int, if you want
}
```

Then,

```
F f = new F(); // this could be a static field somewhere, making it effectively a global variable
Console.WriteLine(f[1][2][3][4].Count);
```

If you really like the method invocation syntax though, you would need to use `dynamic` and inherit from `DynamicObject`, overriding `TryInvoke`, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4858849/5133585).

Example:

```
dynamic f = new F();
Console.WriteLine(f(1)(2)(3)(4).Count);

class F: DynamicObject {
    public int Count { get; }
    public F(int count = 0) {
        Count = count;
    }
    public override Boolean TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, object?[]? args, out object? result) {
        if (args?.Length == 1 && args?[0] is int acc) {
            result = new F(Count + acc);
            return true;
        }
        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```